# Adding new element to a ComboBox which is in a DataGrid in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, combobox, binding, expression-blend

I have a `DataGrid` which contains  `Transactions`. I have an `InterestOrDividend` column where I can select a value using a `ComboBox`. This works fine.

A new feature would be to enter a value and add it to the list of possibilities. I set `IsEditable` to `true` and added `Interaction.Triggers` from `http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity`

Problem 1:
It seems `InterestOrDividendSelectionChangedCommand` not only fires when the selection is changed but also when I scroll the DataGrid and such rows come into view which has a not null value in the `InterestOrDividend` column. Moreover, when a new value is entered (which is not in the list), the event does not fire.

Problem 2:
I want to bind the `Text` property of the `ComboBox` to get the newly added value. It seems the event fire before the `Text` property changes, so I get the old value.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{x:Static r:Resource.InterestOrDividend}"
   CellTemplate="{StaticResource InterestOrDividendEditingTemplate}"
   CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource InterestOrDividendEditingTemplate}" />

<DataTemplate x:Key="InterestOrDividendEditingTemplate">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                            AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.AppData.AlienTypeObjects}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding InterestOrDividend}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="FullName" 
                  IsEditable="True" 
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                        AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, 
                        Path=DataContext.InterestOrDividendSelectionChangedCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource  FindAncestor, 
                        AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}, Path=Text}"
                                           />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ComboBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution. Instead of using the `EventTrigger` I catch the new element in the setter of `NewInterestOrDividend`. It is important that the `UpdateSourceTrigger` is `LostFocus`. When `InterestOrDividend` is null and you change the focus then `value` in `NewInterestOrDividend` contains the new value.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="InterestOrDividendEditingTemplate">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                            AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.AppData.AlienTypeObjects}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="FullName" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxError}" 
                  IsEditable="True" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding InterestOrDividend, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  Text="{Binding NewInterestOrDividend, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
        </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I changed the UpdateSourceTrigger of SelectedItem to PropertyChanged. If it is LostFocus then it is not sure which Binding will run first.